# function in an addEventListener only works for 1 condition, computerChoice is undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a very beginner Rock Paper Scissors program in JavaScript. I have a function `adjustGame` which will reset the scores (`userWs` and `computerWs`) after either of them reach a value of 5 and will display the winner of the game. I use this function after either the user or computer win in a round in an event listener arrow function. The problem is that it won't reset after the computer reaches 5 round wins, but it will for the user.

```js
const weapons = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];

function getComputerChoice() {
  return weapons[Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons.length)];
}

let computerWs = 0;
let userWs = 0;

// DOM
const body = document.body;
const rockButton = document.getElementById("rockButton");
const paperButton = document.getElementById("paperButton");
const scissorsButton = document.getElementById("scissorsButton");
const div = document.getElementById("results");


const scoreboard = document.createElement("h3");
scoreboard.textContent = `User ${userWs} - ${computerWs} Computer`;
div.appendChild(scoreboard);
const result = document.createElement("p");
result.textContent = "";
div.appendChild(result);

function adjustGame() {
  if (computerWs == 5) {
    result.textContent = `The computer won with ${computerChoice}`;
    userWs = 0;
    computerWs = 0;
  } else if (userWs == 5) {
    result.textContent = 'You won!';
    userWs = 0;
    computerWs = 0;
  }
};

rockButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  if (computerChoice == 'Scissors') {
    userWs += 1;
    scoreboard.textContent = `User ${userWs} - ${computerWs} Computer`;
    result.textContent = "Rock beats Scissors!";
    adjustGame();
  } else if (computerChoice == 'Rock') {
    computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    result.textContent = 'Both played Rock.'
    adjustGame();
  } else {
    computerWs += 1;
    scoreboard.textContent = `User ${userWs} - ${computerWs} Computer`;
    result.textContent = "Paper beats Rock!";
    adjustGame();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="rps.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="rockButton">Rock</button>
  <button id="paperButton">Paper</button>
  <button id="scissorsButton">Scissors</button>
  <div id="results">
  <h2>Game Results</h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried changing the else conditional for when the computer wins to an else if condition, I've moved the `adjustGame()` function around under the conditional statements, and neither worked how I wanted it to.

Comment: Without more context it will be difficult to help--if the condition fires the variable will be reset to `0`.

Comment: Please update with HTML that reproduces your challenge I added a snippet to get you started.

Comment: Notice that as this is now it throws an error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')"`

Comment: (Tangential, but the result content is updated immediately after updating so the user will be missing some feedback.)

Comment: `computerChoice` is not reachable in `adjustGame` as it's only available within the scope of the callback given to `.addEventListener()`